SpringBoot How to fix 401 unauthirze on postman
I try to learn Springboot but i have a problem .
I have à ressourcecontroller in my package controller :
package controller;


import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;


@RestController
public class ResourceController {

    @GetMapping("/")
    public String getResource() {
        return "a value...";
    }

}

I have a SpringSecurityConfig in my package configuration :
package configuration;


import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.Customizer;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.http.SessionCreationPolicy;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.provisioning.InMemoryUserDetailsManager;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;


@Configuration
public class SpringSecurityConfig {

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        return http
                .csrf(csrf -> csrf.disable())
                .sessionManagement(session -> session.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS))
                .authorizeHttpRequests(auth -> auth.anyRequest().authenticated())
                .httpBasic(Customizer.withDefaults())
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public UserDetailsService users() {
        UserDetails user = User.builder().username("user").password(passwordEncoder().encode("password")).roles("USER")
                .build();
        return new InMemoryUserDetailsManager(user);
    }


    @Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }


}

i have that on my pom.xml :
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.4</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.p3_oc</groupId>
    <artifactId>chatop_FS</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>chatop_FS</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-oauth2-resource-server</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-j</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>

When I try on Postman this path : GET : localhost:6000
( 6000 because i have that on my application.properties :
#Tomcat configuration
server.port=6000

)
I have no reponse , ERROR - 401 Unauthorized
Some else for help me to inderstand why don't work ?  please ?
And on my postman i have that :


You protected all endpoints and aren't logging in.

I follow this tutorial : https://openclassrooms.com/fr/courses/7137776-securisez-votre-application-web-avec-spring-security/8325571-securisez-votre-api-avec-jwt for learning how to implement jwt with spring

and this is a first part of this tutorial , you know how i can get my http request ?

Then follow the tutorial, which apparently tells you how to do a request WITH login information.

I don't really understand, I entered my spring security information in postman in basic auth by putting user and password in basic auth in postman, it doesn't work... Or maybe I didn't understand it well. Can you just tell me where I went wrong, I'll read again...

@M.Deinum can you explain me please ?

It doesnt look like you are using a correct oauth2 in your example. Can you try to replace
  <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-oauth2-resource-server</artifactId>
  </dependency>

with the spring security starter:
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
</dependency>

It should the use basic-auth what you are referencing.
